# How to out JQuery buttons and key presses for sound and animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I want to replace the Vanilla JavaScript code with the JQuery. Here whenever I click a button on the webpage, it is supposed to play the animation and play the sound. Also, when I press a suitable key, e.g. "w", it is also supposed to play that respective sound. However, I am not sure why it is not working and if it is even possible.

JavaScript

```
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

$("button").on("click", function(){
  makeSound(event.key);
  buttonAnimation(event.key);
});
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  makeSound(event.key);
  buttonAnimation(event.key);
});


function makeSound(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var audio1 = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      audio1.play();
      break;
    case "a":
      var audio2 = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      audio2.play();
      break;
    case "s":
      var audio3 = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      audio3.play();
      break;
    case "d":
      var audio4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      audio4.play();
      break;
    case "j":
      var audio5 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      audio5.play();
      break;
    case "k":
      var audio6 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      audio6.play();
      break;
    case "l":
      var audio7 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      audio7.play();
      break;
    default: console.log()
  }

}

function buttonAnimation(currentKey) {
  var activeButton = document.querySelector("." + currentKey);

  activeButton.classList.add("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {
    activeButton.classList.remove("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>


<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside your button's `onclick` handler you're using `event` without including it as a parameter. Second, the button press would not include a `event.key`, since it is not a keypress event. This is the problem :) The answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(event){
  makeSound(this.classList[0]);
  buttonAnimation(this.classList[0]);
});
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  makeSound(event.key);
  buttonAnimation(event.key);
});


function makeSound(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var audio1 = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      audio1.play();
      break;
    case "a":
      var audio2 = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      audio2.play();
      break;
    case "s":
      var audio3 = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      audio3.play();
      break;
    case "d":
      var audio4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      audio4.play();
      break;
    case "j":
      var audio5 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      audio5.play();
      break;
    case "k":
      var audio6 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      audio6.play();
      break;
    case "l":
      var audio7 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      audio7.play();
      break;
    default: console.log()
  }

}

function buttonAnimation(currentKey) {
  var activeButton = $("." + currentKey);

  activeButton.addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {
    activeButton.removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.pressed {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
```